# Thai noodle dish with peanuts

Tags: thai-cuisine

When I lived in Thailand many years ago, I used to love a fried noodle dish with fresh peanuts on top that was called something that sounded like “goytio hang”. I never saw it spelled in English (or Thai) so I have no idea how to search for a recipe. Can anyone help with the name?

Comment: Kuai-tiao haeng ?

Answer (score 12):

Perhaps you are referring to [guay teow haeng sukhothai](http://thaifoodandtravel.com/blog/thai-noodles/#attachment_5019) (ก๋วยเตี๋ยวแห้งสุโขทัย). It has peanuts on it and it's not pad thai (ผัดไท่ย). Unfortunately, a search using English does not yield a recipe. Lucky for you I can read Thai. Here is a translation of the ingredients list posted in Thai at [Chompoo Kitchen](http://www.pantown.com/board.php?id=5495&area=4&name=board8&topic=19&action=view).

- snake beans, sliced diagonally
- cabbage, trimmed
- bean shoots
- thin rice noodles
- crispy fried garlic
- fish sauce
- salted white radish, finely chopped
- roasted bird pepper powder
- roasted peanuts, ground
- white sugar
- parsley, chopped
- lime wedge
- deep fried dumpling or pork rinds

Along with that they give a recipe for the braised pork

- 5 coriander roots, can substitute coriander seeds
- 30 cloves of asian garlic (small cloves)
- 1 teaspoon green peppercorns
- (almost) 1 tablespoon hoisin sauce
- (almost) 1 tablespoon fermented soybean sauce (not soy sauce)
- 5 cups water
- 500g pork sirloin, 2 inches thick, leave whole
- 300g pork skin
- 1/2 cup white sugar
- 3 teaspoons salt
- light soy sauce as seasoning

Method for sliced pork

1. Roughly crush coriander root (or seeds), garlic, green peppercorns to form a paste then add it to a cooking pot
2. Pour in the water and add the pork and pork skin then put the pot on a medium heat
3. Bring it to the boil, reduce the heat to low, season with the white sugar, salt, hoisin sauce and soybean sauce
4. Adjust the seasoning with the light soy sauce and allow to simmer
5. When cooked and still soft remove the pork and pork skin from the pot and allow to cool
6. Slice the pork and pork skin, place in a container ready for serving time

Method for completing the dish

1. In a pot bring water to a boil then add the noodles, cook until al dente then remove them and put them aside
2. Combine the crispy fried garlic with a little vegetable oil and then combine that with all the pork
3. Blanch the snake beans, bean shoots and cabbage for a few seconds making sure they are still crispy.
4. Add the vegetables to the noodles followed by the pork, vegetables, bird pepper powder, peanuts, salted radish, parsley, lime wedge and fried dumpling wrappers
5. Enjoy

Serves 4 people

You'll find a stack of photos on the original recipe page to help you along.

Answer (score -1):

I found a [list on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Thai_dishes#Noodle_dishes) ... maybe this will help.

Comment: Thanks Joe and Diana.  Joe, you hit the nail on the head.  And Diana your list was terrific, though Kuai-tiao haeng was, unfortunately, not on it.  but from the looks of it, it's a generic street food, so everyone probably makes it differently.

Comment: Just to answer to your speculation, people do make it differently. Kuai-tiao literally means noodle dish and Haeng means "dry" or without soup. The most common street food version with peanuts is probably egg noodle with bean sprouts, fish balls, roast pork, ground pork, and scallions. Enjoy the images at https://www.google.com/search?q=บะหมี่แห้ง&tbm=isch